# Ormlite database helper - onCreate() not called

Tags: android, ormlite

I am using ormlite.android.4.31.jar 
I have typical DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper  extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "realestate.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<TabKraj, Integer> krajDao;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, TabKraj.class);
            initData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to create datbases", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVer, int newVer) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, TabKraj.class, true);
            onCreate(sqliteDatabase, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Unable to upgrade database from version " + oldVer + " to new " + newVer, e);
        }
    }

    public Dao<TabKraj, Integer> getKrajDao() throws SQLException{
        if (krajDao == null) {
            krajDao = getDao(TabKraj.class);
        }
        return krajDao;
    }

    private void initData(){
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "data initiating");

        TabKraj k1 = new TabKraj();
        TabKraj k2 = new TabKraj();

        k1.setNazov("Kosicky kraj");
        k1.setId(1);
        try {
            getKrajDao().create(k1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(Constants.DEBUG_TAG, "Data initialing ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

app is uninstalled, data cleared ...
I am running app in debug mode from eclipse, constructor of `DatabaseHleper` is called but `onCreate()` is not called.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: have you figured out your problem?
I had the same problem, and came here to find an answer. Now I found out that onCreate() will only be called when you actually 'do something' with the database (e.g. insert).

Answer (score 3):

As @k-mera said:

Database file **will be created only if you did some operations in Database like "insert"**.

Answer (score 2):

Although you say the data is cleared, I suspect that Android thinks it has not.  To completely remove the data, I would remove the application and re-install it.

Since your `onUpgrade` calls `onCreate` you could also increase the `DATABASE_VERSION` value which will cause the data to be dropped and re-created.

Comment: Gray: thanks, before running app from eclipse I do Settings-Applications-Manage applications: choosing my app and : force close, clear data and uninstall. Despite of that onCreate is not called. Is that possible that database remain after uninstall? If so how to definitely remove it?

Comment: A have changed field DATABASE_VERSION = 2; But onUpgrade() was not called as well.

Comment: Have you tried to add log statements @falconseye?  Maybe there is something wrong with the debugger.  `Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Running onCreate");`

Comment: @falconseye Is it possible that there are 2 database helpers and you are running the wrong one by accident?

Comment: Gray: just one. I also tried to uninstall and after that rename database in DatabaseHelper. Without success.

Comment: @falconsye Any exceptions in the logs?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the constructor and tracing the code?  How about a breakpoint in `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.onCreate()` to see if that is called.

Comment: Gray: Yes, I have put breakpoints to constructor as well as to onCreate() and onUpgrade(). In constructor it was stopped on breakpoint. I have tried to trace with steps from constructor but there are calls to unreachable code - android or ormlite packages. My launger activity contanits just super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main); and DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Gray: and yes I have put debug statements into both methods.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10348/discussion-between-falconseye-and-gray)