# ORMLite on Android not calling onCreate

Tags: android, ormlite

Using ORMLite v 4.40, I try to get my app running, but it seems to ignore the onCreate function

My DatabaseHelper looks like this (snippet style)

```
public class ORMLiteHelper extends  OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private Context databaseContext;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "InVinoVeritas";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

    public ORMLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.v("ORMLiteHelper", "Cosntructor");
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        Log.v("DatabaseHelper", "onCreate");
    ...
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.v("DatabaseHelper", "onUpgrade");
    ...
```

My MainActivity calls the DatabaseHelper as described:

```
public class MainActivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<ORMLiteHelper>  {
```

I have tried re-installing the application, upgrading the database version, nothing works.
I do see the constructor call (including typo :-), the onCreate and onUpgrade however are not called.

Any help appreciated

Barry

Comment: The only time `onCreate` is called is when the database does not exist.  `onUpgrade` is called when you increase the database version number.  Any change it is calling this routines but you are filtering the debug output?

Comment: P.S. I am aware of the question at the following location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260137/ormlite-database-helper-oncreate-not-called

Comment: I don't think so. I explicitly delete the application using:       ./adb uninstall be.nauta.vino   I also tried upgrading the database version on an existing (read: installed) application, but no luck there either

Comment: How about changing the database name.  Another thing to try is to throw a `RuntimeException` in `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`.  That will show up in the logs.

Comment: Are you looking the logs using `platform-tools/adb logcat` from the command-line?

Comment: Regarding the filtering of the messages: all messages are logged on verbose level. Constructor is shown, onXYZ is not

Comment: I am using logcat as part of the eclipse plugin, yes

Comment: I find that the eclipse plugin is harder than running adb from the command line.  I have to fight with it to have it show my messages.

Comment: :-) Commandline gives the same result. No logs for onXYZ.... The constructor shows. I would not mind continuing this via chat, but I don't have enough credits to start a chat....

Comment: I think @dbiobas is right.  (duh)  It doesn't create the database until you go to use it.  Try calling your `getDao(class)` method to see if your database gets created.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create instance of `ORMLiteHelper` and call `getWritableDatabase()`. When database is not created then onCreate will be invoked.

Comment: Excellent!!! This does the trick (duh indeed....). Thanks for the fast replies. And also: keep up the good work!