# How to check if a Sqlite database exists in android?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm pretty new using ORMLite with android, and I read in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920911/ormlite-on-android-not-calling-oncreate) that the method `onCreate()` of the class `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` is not called when the database already exists... but I'd like to confirm it by myself, does anyone know how to check if the database exists?

Comment: i haven't written a single line of android code in my whole life. here is my answer: an sqlite database is just a file. if the database file exists, the database exists. otherwise it exists not.

Comment: I understand your point, but I read that ORMLite creates the database in a local storage folder... and you can't access that folder without super user permissions, so... that way it's not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: hmm. if sqlite has readaccess there, your app should have too, no? sqlite is just an ordinary library. or are you communicating with it through some local RPC mechanism?

Comment: SQLite is a very light weight database which comes with Android OS. The database exists with 2 two default tables android_metadata & sqlite_sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` inherits the `getWritableDatabase()` method from `SQLiteOpenHelper`. If that method returns null, then the database does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a database by using `SQLiteDatabase` 
for example

```
SQLiteDatabase = StackOverFlowDB;
//Creating database
    StackOverFlowDB = MainActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("StackOverFlow", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```